# O hibernate salva duas vezes a entidade executado dentro do dialog do primefaces

Tags: hibernate, primefaces

Quando o botão salvar está na página ele funciona normalmente e salva a entidade mas eu abro um dialog para confirmar os dados para serem salvos e o hibernate salva duas vezes muito estranho o método para salvar fora do dialog funciona corretamente mas dentro executa duas vezes.

```
<p:dialog id="dialogconfirmarvenda" appendTo="@(body)" widgetVar="dcv" closable="true" width="1000" maximizable="true" binding="#{vendaMB.dialogconfirmarvenda}" minimizable="true" position="top">
    <p:ajax event="close" listener="#{vendaMB.closeDialog()}" />
    <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="CONFIRMAR VENDA" style="font-family: sans-serif"/></f:facet>
    <h:form id="formfinalizarvenda">
        <p:panelGrid id="panelgridconfirmarvenda">
            <p:row>
                <p:column rendered="#{vendaMB.clienteMB.clienteDAO.cliente != null}"><h:outputText value="Cliente" styleClass="text"/></p:column>
                <p:column rendered="#{vendaMB.clienteMB.clienteDAO.cliente != null}"><h:outputText value="#{vendaMB.clienteMB.clienteDAO.cliente.nome}" styleClass="text"/></p:column>
                <p:column><h:outputText value="Pagamento" styleClass="text"/></p:column>
                <p:column><h:outputText value="#{vendaMB.meioPgtoMB.meioPgtoDAO.meiopgto.descricao}" styleClass="text"/></p:column>
                <p:column><h:outputText value="Total da Venda" styleClass="text"/></p:column>
                <p:column><h:outputText value="#{vendaMB.totalVenda}" styleClass="text"><f:convertNumber type="currency"/></h:outputText></p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <p:commandButton actionListener="#{vendaMB.finalizarVenda()}" value="Finalizar" oncomplete="PF('dcv').hide()"/>
                </p:column>
            </p:row>
        </p:panelGrid>
        <p:spacer height="10" width="800"/>
        <p:dataTable id="tableitensvenda" value="#{vendaMB.itemvendaAdds}" var="ivadd">
            <p:column headerText="Código"><h:outputText value="#{ivadd.itemvenda.produto.codigo}"/></p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Produto"><h:outputText value="#{ivadd.itemvenda.produto.descricao}"/></p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Preço">
                <h:outputText value="#{ivadd.itemvenda.valor}">
                    <f:convertNumber type="currency"/>
                </h:outputText>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Qtd"><h:outputText value="#{ivadd.itemvenda.quantidade}"/></p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Total"><h:outputText value="#{ivadd.total}"><f:convertNumber type="currency"/></h:outputText></p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

Este é o dialog para exibir os dados para confirmação.
O link que abre o dialog:

```
<p:commandLink value="venda" title="Confirmar Venda" oncomplete="PF('dcv').show()" actionListener="#{vendaMB.confirmarVenda}" />

public void confirmarVenda() {
    for (Meiopgto meiopgto : meioPgtoMB.getMeiopgtos()) {
        if (meiopgto.getIdmeiopgto().equals(idmeiopgto)) {
            meioPgtoMB.getMeioPgtoDAO().setMeiopgto(meiopgto);
            break;
        }
    }
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(Arrays.asList("formvenda", "dialogconfirmarvenda"));
}
```

Comment: Ronaldo, bem vindo ao Stack Overflow. Para que possamos auxiliá-lo adequadamente é importante que você forneça as informações relevantes do ponto de vista técnico. Isso incluí enxertos de código, markup, configurações e tudo mais que for necessário para reproduzir o seu problema. Dê uma lida em [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) e tome o tempo que precisar para atualizar a pergunta.

Comment: Ronaldo, poderia incluir o código do botão que abre o `Dialog`? A minha suposição é que o botão tem um `action` chamando o método `vendaMB.finalizarVenda()`, e além de abrir o `Dialog` ele salva as informações.

Comment: Não esqueca de fazer uma menção (@Nome), senão eu não sou notificado. A minha sugestão seria colocar um Breakpoint no método que é chamado duas vezes e olhar o stacktrace para ver como ele é chamado nessas duas vezes. Isso talvez dê uma dica do problema.

Comment: Ronaldo, eu queria que você colocasse um **Breakpoint** e debugasse no método que faz a chamada ao JPA. E se possivel incluir o stacktrace que aparece na perspectiva de Debug.

Comment: Algumas possibilidades (o problema de não ter um [MVCE](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) é não poder afirmar nada com precisão). Será que seu dialog não está dentro de um form e isso está disparando o evento duas vezes? Será que algum outro `listener` como `#{vendaMB.closeDialog()}` ou `#{vendaMB.finalizarVenda()}` não está chamando esse método?

Comment: @Anthony Accioly eu retirei o **binding="#{vendaMB.dialogconfirmarvenda}"** e funcionou - não sei por que - e valeu pela ajuda.

Comment: @RonaldoSantos, como você deve ter visto no [tour], você pode aceitar uma resposta, não utilize a abordagem de "Resolvido" no título como normalmente é feito em fóruns. Nessa pergunta em questão, você poderia elaborar uma resposta dizendo como chegou na solução e depois aceitá-la.

Answer (score 1):

Eu resolvi o problema removendo o **binding="#{vendaMB.dialogconfirmarvenda}"** do Dialog